# Proving Combinations questions through Mathematical Induction (2-Variable Mathematical Induction)

Tags: algebra-precalculus, number-theory, induction, combinations

So I was wrestling with the following question, where I was asked to prove:
$$\frac{n!}{\:\left(n-r\right)!\cdot r!}+\frac{n!}{\left(n-r-1\right)!\cdot\left(r+1\right)!}=\frac{\left(n+1\right)!}{\left(n-r\right)!\cdot \left(r+1\right)!}$$

I tried to do this through algebra, but it turns out I can't write $\frac{n!}{\:\left(n-r\right)!\cdot r!} as \frac{n\left(n-r\right)!}{\left(n-r\right)!\cdot r!}$

I thought I could try this through Mathematical induction, but I don't know how to do this using 2 variables.

Please help!

Comment: You can write $(n-r)!$ as $(n-r)(n-r-1)!$ and $(r+1)!$ as $(r+1)r!$.

Comment: For math. induction on two variables $m$ and $n$, first set $m=0$ and make induction on $n$. Then make the induction step for $m$ and make induction $n$.

Comment: @PJK Thanks! I managed to solve now!

Comment: @Wuestenfux Could you please explain how to do that? How should I eventually combine the two inductions? Thanks!

Comment: Indeed. First $n=0$ (base): $m=0$ (base) and $0,\ldots, m\mapsto m$ or $m\mapsto m+1$ (step). Second $0,\ldots,n\mapsto n+1$ or $n\mapsto n+1$ (step) and $m=0$ (base) and $0,\ldots,m\mapsto m+1$ or $m\mapsto m+1$ (step).